# Plotly's treemap and sunburst show wrong sizes

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, treemap, sunburst-diagram

I am trying to use plotly's sunburst and treemap to visualize data. However, I discovered that the child nodes show wrong size compared to their parents, that is, the sum of children's size does not cover that of the parents:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig =go.Figure(go.Treemap(
    labels= ["i_1", "i_2", "c_a", "i_3", "c_b"],
    parents= ["c_a", "c_a", "", "c_b", ""], 
    values= [3, 2, 5, 2, 2],
))

fig.show()
```

The output:

[image: Treemap output]

As you can see, in the raw data, i_1 and i_2 together have a sum of 5, equal their parent c_a's 5. But in the graph, the "c_a" block is not filled up by i_1 and i_2 together. Same goes for i_3 and c_b. Even though the mouseover popups show the correct values.

Same goes for the sunburst visualization:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig =go.Figure(go.Sunburst(
    labels= ["i_1", "i_2", "c_a", "i_3", "c_b"],
    parents= ["c_a", "c_a", "", "c_b", ""], 
    values= [3, 2, 5, 2, 2],
))

fig.show()
```

[image: sunburst graph]

Again, i_1 and i_2 together do not cover the whole scope of c_a.

Are the settings to force plotly to truthfully represent the proportions of the father-child sizes. To be honest, the current representation is not usable for my purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, set `branchvalues="total"`. The default is `"remainder"` which adds the value to the sum of the children, as you see in your figures. You could also leave that setting alone and set the value for all non-leaf nodes to 0.

Comment: It seems in the case of large data set, the branchvalues makes or breaks the  jupyter run. Small dataset? OK. Large dataset? The cell finishes the run quickly, but the output is white out. A bug with this parameter?

Comment: Some users have reported this behaviour but no one has yet been able to share a dataset that causes this so that our development team can replicate and fix it... If you have such a dataset or reproducible code example, please please do file an issue here and we will fix it: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/new

Comment: the data I worked on was from Kaggle's Predict future sales "https://www.kaggle.com/c/competitive-data-science-predict-future-sales", the sales_train.csv.gz to be exact. However, user needs to agree to the competition's term to have access, so it would be better that you visit the website and proceed. The code I tried was to plot the sales' amount of all items and embedded in their categories (parents). All I got was an empty cell with branchvalues="total", perhaps even without the argument.